# Design changes in SO?

Tags: discussion, design

Did StackOverflow just undergo some design changes? I think maybe my eyes were playing tricks, I tried to zoom-in the page back to 100%, but it's still evident...

Like the Upvote/Downvote buttons are more spaced-out from the vote couter.
Same thing is visible in Meta.

Is there a known list of changes?

Comment: @bluet That one is from Nov. 2014

Comment: SOMEONE STOLE ALL THE **[HYPERLINK UNDERLINES](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/guidelines-for-visualizing-links/)**. I THINK I'M GONNA DIE!!!

Comment: WHAT!!! Holy Cached $#!+ !!! That's a minor shock :P

Comment: the "duplicate" link above was posted 2 months ago while the design change only appeared this morning (at my place)